# Nats.io QueueSubscribe behavior on timeout

Tags: go, microservices, nats.io

I'm evaluating NATS for migrating an existing msg based software 
I did not find documentation about msg timeout exception and overload. 
For Example:

- After Subscriber has been *chosen* , Is it aware of timeout settings posted by Publisher ? Is it possible to notify an additional time extension ?
- If the *elected* subscriber is aware that some DBMS connection is missing and cannot complete It could be possible to bounce the message

NATS server will pickup another subscriber and will re-post the same message ?

Ciao
Diego

Comment: I notice that NATS Streaming Server has Queue as well and there is an option named *ManualAck* and re-delivery behavior (see https://github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/issues/186 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: It seems to me that you are trying to publish a request message with a timeout (using the `nc.Request`). If so, the timeout is managed by the client. Effectively the client publishes the request message and creates a subscription on the reply subject. If the subscription doesn't get any messages within the timeout it will notify you of the timeout condition and unsubscribe from the reply subject.

On your second question - are you using a queue group? A queue group in NATS is a subscription that specifies a queue group name. All subscriptions having the same queue group name are treated specially by the server. The server will select one of the queue group subscriptions to send the message to rotating between them as messages arrive. However the responsibility of the server is simply to deliver the message.

To do what you describe, implement your functionality using request/reply using a timeout and a max number of messages equal to 1. If no responses are received after the timeout your client can then resend the request message after some delay or perform some other type of recovery logic. The reply message should be your 'protocol' to know that the message was handled properly. Note that this gets into the design of your messaging architecture. For example, it is possible for the timeout to trigger after the request recipient received the message and handled it but before the client or server was able to publish the response. In that case the request sender wouldn't be able to tell the difference and would eventually republish. This hints that such type of interactions need to make the requests idempotent to prevent duplicate side effects.

Comment: Also NATS Streaming is a completely different thing. A NATS streaming server captures all messages in a log. The NATS streaming server 'replays' the log to a NATS streaming subscriber. Like NATS a subscriber can be a member of a queue group, and messages in the log will get distributed between the queue group members.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! I agree with your final sentence: _...make the requests idempotent to prevent duplicate side effects..._  It is exactly the critical *piece* of code that I had to code within the current pub/sub architecture. I will clone my test env into a simple NATS pub sub and I will retest all recovery scenarios.